# Rails 4 Send Grid Bypass List Management X-SMTPAPI header

Tags: header, ruby-on-rails-4, sendgrid

I am trying to ensure that a request for a new password gets sent to a user's email even if they are on the unsubscribed list. I have included my reset_password function:

def reset_password_instructions(record, opts={}, info)

```
headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = {
                        :filters => {:bypass_list_management => { :settings => { :enable => 0 } } }
                       }.to_json
super
```

end

Am I sending over the header incorrectly?

Here is the relevant link from the sendgrid docs - http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/apps.html. This filter I am using is at the bottom.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `enable` to `1`.

Your current configuration turns the app off, instead of on. If you change it to, the following it should work:

```
def reset_password_instructions(record, opts={}, info)
    headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = {
        :filters => {:bypass_list_management => { :settings => { :enable => 0 } } }
    }.to_json
    super
end
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! I originally had that and found a resource online that recommended otherwise. But their way also gave me an error with my header and the team at SG helped me fix it. Sendgrid support is incredible!!

Comment: Glad to hear it! We're here to help. Let us know if you need anything else.